# How to customize Readline keybindings of GHCi?

Tags: haskell, readline, ghc

I know GHCi supports Readline, and keybindings such as `^W`  and `^U` work as expected.

I do wonder whether ghci support customization of keybindings the way Bash deals with inputrc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is your GHC version?  GHCi stopped using readline and started using [libedit](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) around 6.10 and [haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/haskeline) around 6.12.

libedit can be configured in [`~/.editrc`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=editrc); similarly, Haskeline has [`~/.haskeline`](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/UserPrefs).  For example, I have

```
# ~/.editrc (for libedit)
edit on
bind ^R em-inc-search-prev
bind ^S em-inc-search-next
bind ^[[5~ ed-search-prev-history
bind ^[[6~ ed-search-next-history
```

to match my

```
# ~/.inputrc (for readline)
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Comment: Some links are dead

Comment: This is not a full replacement, `ed-search-prev-history` moves the cursor to the end of the line, while `history-search-backward` doesn't. What is the *libedit* command which doesn't move the cursor?

Comment: This is a more current solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883574

Answer (score 2):

@ephemient's answer above also helps with newer builds of MySQL which have switched from readline to libedit.  I used

```
$ ~/.editrc:
bind ^[[A ed-search-prev-history
bind ^[[B ed-search-next-history
```

to match my old version which used to work inside MySQL:

```
$ ~/.inputrc:
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

(my only annoyance now is that if I just want to scroll and not search, I have to type a "." first to match every line).