# Set vi as editor in GHCi

Tags: haskell, vim, read-eval-print-loop, archlinux, ghci

How can I get vi editing mode to work in GHCi?

I'm using version 7.10.3.

I tried `Prelude> :set editor vi`, but to no effect.

I also have these lines in my `~/.inputrc`.

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

.

Comment: After you `:set editor vi`, what happens when you try to `:edit` a file? What do you mean "to no effect"?

Comment: I do not mean to edit a file. "To no effect" means I can't get vi editing mode to work in GHCi, like it does not work when I press ESC to get into command mode to navigate/edit a text. In Bash shell i can do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the readline keybindings of ghci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825547/how-to-customize-the-readline-keybindings-of-ghci)

Comment: there is some *VI editing mode* in GHCi? ... Or are you talking about setting up some GHCi REPL support for VI?

Comment: @Carsten yes there is

Answer (score 36, accepted):

GHCi now uses the [Haskeline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) library for command line editing (which has been true for quite a while now), and it does indeed have a vi mode. The configuration file is `~/.haskeline` and the line you want is:

```
editMode: Vi
```

Documented here: https://github.com/judah/haskeline/wiki/UserPreferences

Comment: I've just started using it and I noticed that the `;` and `,` commands to repeat `f` or `F` commands in one or the other direction do not work...

Comment: [Issue #60](https://github.com/judah/haskeline/issues/60) on GitHub is just about this.

Answer (score 0):

This works without any issues on MacOS with The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.4.3

```
ghci> :set editor vi
ghci> :edit <yourfilename>
```